# What is the advantage of using dependency injection with providers in Flutter's riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I often see people talking about using riverpod when defining dependencies for each class in flutter.

```dart
final apiClientProvider = Provider.autoDispose(
  (_) => GithubApiClientImpl(),
);

final githubRepositoryProvider = Provider.autoDispose(
  (ref) => GithubRepositoryImpl(ref.read(apiClientProvider)),
);

final repositoryListViewModelProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose(
  (ref) => RepositoryListViewModel(ref.read(githubRepositoryProvider)),
);
```

However, I do not understand the benefits of why it is a good idea to use riverpod.
Shouldn't it be initialized at the time of use as shown below?

I feel that the following writing style is sufficient in terms of testing, for example, you can initialize the mock with a test file.

```dart
final githubRepository = GithubRepositoryImpl(GithubApiClientImpl());

final repositoryListViewModel = RepositoryListViewModel(GithubRepositoryImpl(GithubApiClientImpl()));
```

Why bother using riverpod?

Answer (score 0):

1  - there is nothing that gets initialized out of the box it get initialized first time someone request it for example `ref.read(fooProvider)`

the docs:
https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/providers#creating-a-provider

```
Do not be frightened by the global aspect of providers. Providers are fully immutable. Declaring a provider is no different from declaring a function, and providers are testable and maintainable.
```

2  - for mocking you can override a provider see the docs for more info

https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/cookbooks/testing#overriding-the-behavior-of-a-provider-during-tests